# Remove all brackets in filename

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames, rename

I've been trying to remove all brackets in my filename(s).
Can anyone help me create a bash script to do that?

This bash script below work flawlessly for non-bracket filename(s),
but if there are any brackets, it will double the filename:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fname in *; do
    name="${fname%\.*}"
    extension="${fname#$name}"
    newname="${name//[/}"
    newfname="$newname""$extension"
    if [ "$fname" != "$newfname" ]; then
        #echo mv "$fname" "$newfname"
        mv "$fname" "$newfname"
    fi
done
```

Sample output:

```
$ touch [test]
$ ls
[test] rep.sh
$ bash rep.sh
$ ls
rep.sh  test][test]
```

So it did remove the left bracket but it repeated the filename.

Answer (score 3):

i found this one liner and this work :

```
for x in *[*; do mv -- "$x" "${x//[/}"; done
```

this should do the job , just replace left or right bracket each time yu execute this commandl

Comment: you can lose the trailing `/`; so `"${x//[}"` instead of `"${x//[/}"`

Comment: Make that `"${x//[][]}"` to replace both brackets. (Yes, it does look weird.)

Answer (score 1):

Solution posted by @juicebyah will only remove the initial bracket. If OP wants to remove both brackets, it is better to use `sed` in this way:

```
find . -type f -iname "*[*" | \
while IFS= read -r line; \
do mv "$line" "$(printf %s "$line" | sed -re 's/(\[|\])//g')"; done;
```

Comment: nice! it works , remove all brackets in filename.

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler with `rename` embedded in a two-liner:

```
while rename ] '' *; do true; done
while rename [ '' *; do true; done
```

`rename` replaces the first occurrence of $1 with $2 in filename(s) in $3+ and this block removes any and all brackets in all file-and-directorynames in *CWD*.

Comment: All I get when trying this is "syntax error at (user-supplied code) line 3, at EOF \ Missing right curly or square bracket at (user-supplied code) line 4, at end of line"

Comment: Are you using BASH or ZSH? Are you sure you've copied the code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the filename gets doubled is that if `$fname` is `[test]`, then

```
name="${fname%\.*}"
extension="${fname#$name}"
```

results in:

```
name=[test]
extension=[test]
```

(Explanation below.) Later, when `$extension` is concatenated to `$newname`, you'll get `test][test]`.

What you should have used:

```
name=${fname%.*}
extension=${fname#"$name"}
```

The quotes around the parameter expansion are unnecessary (in this case) because word-splitting doesn't happen after parameter expansion in variable assignments. Also, there is nothing special about `.`, so there was no need to backslash-escape it.

But the quotes around `$name` in the second line are essential; if the expansion of `$name` is not quoted, it will be treated as a glob pattern, and it's value `[test]` will be interpreted as "a single <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>t</kbd>". That doesn't prefix-match `$fname`, so without those quotes, `extension` is just set to the value of `$fname`.

Independent of the above, you can remove all brackets from a name with:

```
${fname//[][]/}
```

The pattern is a character class; within a character class, `]` is considered an ordinary character if it is the first character in the class, and `[` is always considered an ordinary character. So the character class consists of `]` and `[` in that order.